# Cannot write more than 204800 characters in a file?

Tags: python, html, file-io, debian, linux-mint

EDIT 2 : For those of you who'd like to get a closer look at the code, here it is : 
https://github.com/pikzen/ffbookmark/blob/python-rewrite/ffbookmark.py

I'm having a bit of a trouble here : python throws an IOError whenever I try to write more than 204800 characters into a file. I tried on another computer, and it crashed at 768k characters. Is it a python problem, is the OS limiting something ? Here's the code I'm using :

```
with open('out.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(items, f)
```

`items` is a simple dictionary. I'm building it from an HTML file containing about 800 elements. Each element is built like this :

```
bookmark = {}
            bookmark["title"] = link.contents[0]
            bookmark["id"] = id
            bookmark["parent"] = 5
            bookmark["dateAdded"] = 1
            bookmark["lastModified"] = 1
            bookmark["type"] = "text/x-moz-place"
            uri = link.get('href')
            # Shaarli's self links are totally messed up : ?xGRpkrp
            # But we can't simply oust links containing '?'s, because
            # php uses it, and pretty much everything does
            # however, if there's not dot, we can assume it's a 
            # Shaarli link.
            # If it's not, well too bad, false positive.
            if "?" in uri and not '.' in uri:
                bookmark['uri'] = "about:blank"
            else:
                bookmark['uri'] = uri
            id += 1

            try:
                # This line messes up when the end of the file has been reached
                # Rather than coding properly, let's just catch the exception
                desc = link.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling
                if desc and desc.name == "dd":
                    bookmark["annos"] = []
                    annos = {}
                    annos["name"] = "bookmarkProperties/description"
                    annos["flags"] = 0
                    annos["expires"] = 4
                    annos["mimeType"] = ""
                    annos["type"] = 3
                    annos["value"] = desc.contents[0]
                    bookmark["annos"].append(annos)
```

Output :

```
IOError (Errno 27) : File too large
```

EDIT : Additionnal info :
Python info :

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

OSes used :

Linux Mint 13 : limit : 204.8kB

Debian 6.0 : limit : 768kB

Comment: Can you give us a simple construction of `items` (`[[] * 10] * 1000` or something) that hits this limit?

Comment: and the first and second OS you used were...? please be as specific as possible, including version, SP, and whatever may help people understand the context...

Comment: This could be file system, security, or other types of disk limitations, but is definitely not python.

Comment: @Eric : I added an example in the post. When I go over about 800 elements, it reaches this limit. However, the problem does not come from the json dump : I can write to file without any problem if it's small enough. Also, I tried writing 240000 random characters to a file : it failed again after 204800 characters

Comment: What does `ulimit -a` output?

Comment: @DerekLitz : file size               (blocks, -f) 200. Brained by ulimit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a Python error, but a limitation of the filesystem you're writing to, or an equivalent (artificial) restriction of your operating system.

Use `ulimit -f` to check your file size limit. It should say `unlimited`. If it doesn't, you will most likely want to edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`. You can use the following command to search for the problematic configuration:

```
grep fsize /etc/security/limits.conf /etc/security/limits.d/ -r
```

You may also want to check your [filesystem `quota`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/quota) or grsecurity limits.

Lastly, you may want to check `mount` to ensure that the filesystem you expect to be mounted is the one you see.

Comment: 204.8kiB is pretty far from 4GiB. And even then, not FAT32 involved, just Ext3

Comment: @pikzen Are you absolutely certain that that's the problem? Because then, your demo code would look like `open('out.json', 'wb').write(b'A' * 204800)`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Pretty much. Fun fact : this code fails too, after 204800 characters.

Comment: @pikzen Well, no offense, but since `open('out.json', 'wb').write(b'A' * 204800)` is way simpler than your code, [it makes for a way better question](http://sscce.org/#short). Updated the answer with other possibilities.

Comment: I'm having a hard time guessing if it's sarcasm or just smartassery.

My code outputs stuff to a file, your code outputs stuff to a file. Whether this stuff makes any sense or not does not change the problem.

Comment: @pikzen I think he is right. Making the question as simple as possible helps with getting more answers. And since his code seems to trigger the same problem, it's a good minimal code to reproduce the main issue.